# EditText Styling

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to manipulate the style of a text field found in `API 17` of android in `API 8` ??

The text field in lower API's are very different in comparison with the higher API's. Is there any way to give a uniform look and feel for these components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the EditText? Or do you want every widget to look like pre holo widgets? If so, then setting this as your theme will help:

```
<application
       [...]
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme" >
       [...]
</application>
```

However if you just want to have the EditText to be "un-holofied" you can do this:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/spinnermap"
      style="@style/MyEditText"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="android:Widget.Spinner"></style>
```

and set your Theme to Holo(.Light) and Theme(.Light) for pre HC.

Or if you want to combine everything into one theme with everything except the EditText widget being holo, then you can do this:

values-v11/styles.xml: // v11 because pre HC themes already have the EditText style, you want.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo"       
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyEditText></item>
</style>
```

Comment: is it the same using the sherlock themes ??

Comment: Yeah, just set the parent to the sherlock theme

Comment: Doing the following 
<style name = "autoStyle" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    </style>
gives me the resource not found error, I have set the abs as a library too.

Comment: Change it to <style name = "autoStyle" parent = "@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">

Answer (score 4):

To use Android v8 EditText style, change the background of the editText:

android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"

or use the whole style used in v8:

```
<style name="Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMediumInverse</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this:

https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere

if you want to have Holo on older devices (I mean that you can do it in the opposite way - change old controls to look line new ones). This library also works with ActionBar Sherlock.